# sum of elements in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

We have a mysql table which has following schema

```
item varchar(20)
count int
```

We have a chart which classifies the items into categories (item1 and item2 belongs to cat1 and item3, item4 belongs to cat4, but that is not in a table and we cannot create a table.

I want the count of items present in the cat1 and cat2. Can this be done without joining with any table and with inner query ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 
  c.categoryname, 
  SUM(IFNULL(i.`count`,0))
FROM 
(
   SELECT 'item1' itemname, 'cat1' CategoryName
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'item2' , 'cat1'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'item3' , 'cat2'
   UNION ALL
   ...
) c
LEFT JOIN items i ON c.itemname = i.item
GROUP BY c.categoryname
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0bba/6)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  'Cat1', sum(table1.count) FROM Table1 WHERE item IN ('Item1','Item2') UNION SELECT 'Cat2', sum(table1.count) FROM Table1 WHERE item IN ('Item3','Item4');
```

Comment: when i use this query in oracle it is giving me an error "cat1" : invalid identifier

Comment: I was using a double quote, later i made it single quote and put 'cat1' as category and it worked.